# How to match a MM/DD/YYYY date string format in C

Tags: c

I want to check if the string contains only this format: `"02d/02d/04d"`.

I'm using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int iD, iM, iY = 0;
    char str[255] = "01/15/1958534234";
    int number_split = sscanf(str, "%02d/%02d/%04d", &iD, &iM, &iY);

    if ( number_split == 3 )
    {
        printf("Correct Match");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not Correct Match");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But the program print is always `Correct Match`.

Expected output:

```
12/05/1565   => Correct Match
01/05/156419 => Not Correct Match
```

Comment: Well your string is also constant in length so just checking `strlen(str) == 10` too should be enough.

Comment: `scanf()` does not match the entire input it merely tries to find the expected format from the beginning of the input. The rest of the input is discarded.

Comment: `strlen(str) == 10` isn't enough because it accepts `"12/34/5aaa"`.

Comment: If you only want to check the format but not convert the values, why not use a regular expression, or a very simple one with a bunch of calls to `isdigit`.  I don't see the need to actually convert the values to integers.  Also, you need to consider that `sscanf` will happily accept negative values when using `%d`.

Comment: @TheRight I realize my edit added in "date"--if this wasn't your intent, OP, feel free to edit that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the digits, you'll see the problem:

```
printf("[%d][%d][%d]\n", iD, iM, iY); // => [1][15][1958]
```

`sscanf` is fine with there being trailing characters after the year. You can reject trailing characters by modifying your conditional to include a check that the length is exactly 10 characters:

```
if (number_split == 3 && strlen(str) == 10)
```

But this fails on `"1a/2a/3aaa"`. You can add another condition to prevent this:

```
if (number_split == 3 && strlen(str) == 10 && iY > 999)
```

But `sscanf` also accepts negative numbers. You could use

```
if (number_split == 3 && strlen(str) == 10 && iY > 999 && iM >= 0 && iD > 0)
```

But `sscanf` will allow leading whitespace, so a check for that is still necessary:

```
if (number_split == 3 && strlen(str) == 10 && 
    iY > 999 && iM > 0 && iD > 0 && isdigit(str[0]))
```

This still allows `99/99/2020` so more validation may be necessary if you want to make sure the numbers are actual dates.

Answer (score 1):

> How to match a MM/DD/YYYY date string format in C
>
> "02d/02d/04d"

Using `sscanf` is tempting, but it will ignore leading whitespaces before numbers, so `%02d` will match `"99"` and `"            99"` and also `" 1"`! Just do what you really want:

```
int check_mm_dd_yyyy(const char *str) {
   return isdigit((unsigned char)str[0]) &&
          isdigit((unsigned char)str[1]) &&
          str[2] == '/' &&
          isdigit((unsigned char)str[3]) &&
          isdigit((unsigned char)str[4]) &&
          str[5] == '/' &&
          isdigit((unsigned char)str[6]) &&
          isdigit((unsigned char)str[7]) &&
          isdigit((unsigned char)str[8]) &&
          isdigit((unsigned char)str[9]) &&
          str[10] == '\0';
}
```

Comment: Instead of going over every digits twice, you can replace `strlen(str) == 10` with a final `!str[10]`

Comment: Och I can, because I check one after another. So `issdigit(str[0])` will fail if `str[0] = '\0'`, right

Comment: It might be tempting to restrict the check on `str[0]` to the range `0`..`3`, and the check on `str[3]` to `0` or `1`, and maybe the value in `str[6]` to (perhaps `0` and) `1` or `2`.  It depends on the range of years you wish to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to stay with `sscanf()`:

```
%*2[0-9]  Scan 1 to 2 digits, do not save
%*4[0-9]  Scan 1 to 4 digits, do not save
%n        Save offset of scan

int n = 0;
sscanf(str, "%*2[0-9]/%*2[0-9]/%*4[0-9]%n", &n);
bool success = (n == 10) && str[n] == '\0';
```

["That's all Folks!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9434BoGkNQ)

Comment: I knew what that was before even going to the page -- you sir are showing your age...Back when there were only 5 VHF channels and 1 UHF channel in Big-D (and the north city limits was Loop 12).